# Insert into identity column in pgsql

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON
```

This command is giving me error and I need to insert a value into identity column in Postgresql.

Comment: Just update it. There is no need for such a command. You just need to make sure to synchronize the sequence to reflect what you have done. Otherwise the sequence will generate a value that is already present the next time you use it.

Comment: It is not allowing me to update the column value as its an identity column.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have an "identity" column. It only has columns which are populated from a sequence and you moste definitely can update those. What is the error message you get when updating? See here for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12

Comment: error message: " cannot set an identity column to a value [SQL State=0A000]"

Comment: It looks like you're using MS SQL server, not postgresql

Comment: I agree with Daniel. You are definitely **not** using Postgres

Comment: I am using Amazon Redshift which is Postgresql backend. I just found out that Serial datatype is unsupported in redshift.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The number and relevance of [Unsupported PostgreSQL features](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html) in Redshift is such that it looks like an entirely different product. You'll need to mention redshift in further questions (there's no such tag yet in S.O. apparently)